# Normal subgroup with index that divides n!

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Is this argument valid?

If $G$ is a finite group with $n$ Sylow $p$-subgroups (in particular $n = 1$ mod $p$ and $n$ divides $|G|$), then $G$ permutes them acting by conjugation. Therefore there is a homomorphism $\phi: G \to S_n$ (the symmetric group on $n$ elements). If we consider the kernel of this map, then it is a normal subgroup of $G$ with index $|G|/|\phi(G)|$, which in particular divides $|S_n| = n!$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

What does the first isomorphism theorem tell you?

---

Note that the **size** of the kernel is $|G|/|\phi(G)|$, not the **index** of the kernel.

Comment: Right! My concern is on defining that homomorphism (if it is well-defined)

Comment: Oh! Okay. Well, can you write out what the map’s definition is? Let’s say that the $n$ Sylvow $p$-groups are $P_1,\dots,P_n$. How does an element $g\in G$ yield a permutation of $\{1,\dots,n\}$?